# A question about Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, free-modules, syzygies

Let $A=K[t_1,\dots, t_d]$ the ring of the polynomials in $d$ indeterminates. I know that a consequence of Serre's Theorem is that $gldim(A)=d$.

---

PROPOSITION 1.
If $M$ is a finitely generated **projective** module over $A$, then $M$ is free.

PROPOSITION 2.
If $M$ is a finitely generated **projective** module over $A$, then $M$ has a finite free resolution of the form
$0\to F_k\to\dots\to F_1\to F_0\to M\to 0$ with $F_i$ free over $A$ for all $i=0,\dots, k$ and with $k\le d$.

---

I have some difficulties in showing this two proposition. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Currently, both 1 and 2 talk about the same kind of module $M$ (finitely generated and projective.) So if 1 is true, then wouldn’t $0 \to M \to M \to 0$ be a resolution as needed for 2? In view of this, the combination of both statements seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: I'd second @JendrikStelzner's comment, and ask whether there's maybe something garbled in the question... ?

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 1 is the celebrated Quillen-Suslin theorem. [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen%E2%80%93Suslin_theorem) on the Quillen-Suslin Theorem gives links to the original papers and more information. Lang's *Algebra* contains an exposition of a later and shorter proof by Vaserstein, but even that is several pages long.

It is not an intended as an insult if I say that it is not surprising that you had some problems proving Proposition 1!

Proposition 2 is just the Hilbert Syzygy Theorem (or at least, the Hilbert Syzygy Theorem is the same statement without the requirement that $M$ is projective).

Comment: Is there a way to deduce proposition 1 from proposition 2 ?

Comment: @Grace53 Since proposition 1 was a famous open problem for many years, long after proposition 2 was known, it's probably safe to say that there's no *easy* way to deduce proposition 1 from proposition 2. I'm not familiar enough with the proofs of the Quillen-Suslin theorem to say whether any of them could reasonably be described as "deducing proposition 1 from proposition 2".